# Can't send $id parameter to controller function Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm trying to use a custom function in my controller to do a soft delete in my database, but I'm getting the following error.

> Too few arguments to function
> App\Http\Controllers\EspecialidadesController::borrarEspecialidad(), 0
> passed in
> D:\xampp\htdocs\SistemaHNF\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php
> on line 54 and exactly 1 expected

It looks that the `$id` is not reaching the controller function. I'm going to post the code of the controller, view, and routes.

**View**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">

    <h1>Editar Especialidad</h1>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Register') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="post" action="{{ route('especialidades.borrarEspecialidad', $especialidad) }}">
                        @csrf
                        @method('PUT')
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="nombre" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Nombre') }}</label>
                            
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="nombre" type="text"  readonly class="form-control-plaintext" class="form-control @error('nombre') is-invalid @enderror" name="nombre" value="{{ $especialidad->nombre }}" required autocomplete="nombre" autofocus>
                                @error('nombre')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">
                                    {{ __('Borrar') }}
                                </button>
                                <a class=" button btn btn-primary"href="{{route('especialidades.index')}}">Cancelar</a>        
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

**Controller**

```
public function borrarEspecialidad($id)
{
    var_dump($id);
    $especialidad = Especialidades::findOrFail($id);
    $especialidad->estado = false;

    if ($especialidad->save()) {
        return redirect()->route('especialidades.index');
    } else {
        return redirect()->route('especialidades.borrar');
    }
}
```

**Routes**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
Route::get('/especialidades/borrar/{nombre}',[EspecialidadesController::class,'borrar'])->name('especialidades.borrar');
Route::put('/especialidades/delete',[EspecialidadesController::class,'borrarEspecialidad'])->name('especialidades.borrarEspecialidad');
Route::resource('/especialidades', EspecialidadesController::class);
Route::get('/gestionarMedicos', [PersonaController::class,'mostrarMedicos'])->name('personaMostrarMedicos');
Route::get('editarMedico',[PersonaController::class])->name('editarMedicos');
```

I'm new to Laravel, and also English isn't my main language, and I haven't found an answer to my problem on the internet.

Comment: Solved the problem, I was sending the wrong parameter. Instead of {nombre} I needed {id}. Also important to remember to new people like myself you don't need to use the $ when sending parameters in routes

Answer (score 0):

For Route try this

```
Route::post('/especialidades/delete',[EspecialidadesController::class,'borrarEspecialidad'])->name('especialidades.borrarEspecialidad');
```

In your blade

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('especialidades.borrarEspecialidad') }}">
   @csrf
   <input name="id" value="{{$yourModel->id ?? 0}}" hidden>
</form>
```

Controller

```
public function borrarEspecialidad(Request $request)
{
   $id = $request['id'];
   $especialidad = Especialidades::findOrFail($id);
   $especialidad->estado = false;

   if ($especialidad->save()) {
       return redirect()->route('especialidades.index');
   } else {
       return redirect()->route('especialidades.borrar');
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I just managed to solve the problem. It was because I was sending wrong the parameter. I had to send the id and also without the $ sign. Maybe your solution also works.